# How do I break up a file into multiple files based on what is between two strings

Tags: linux, xml, bash

I have a file that contains about 5GB worth of text.
I would like to break this up into multiple smaller files based on each time a specific string comes up.

What I am trying to do is put together a script or even a one liner that reads through the file looking for `<ticket>` and `</ticket>` and each time it finds those it copies those two lines plus the content in between to a new file. Each time it finds a match for those strings I need it to create a new file though.
What thought would do this for me is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash


i=0
for f in BF_File.xml; do
        let i++;
        sed 's#.*<ticket>\(.*\)</ticket>#\1#' "$f" > Smaller_File_"${i}".xml
done
```

but this just ends up copying the contents of the original file into a `Smaller_File_1.xml`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks to show us **sample input** and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `<ticket>` and `</ticket>` pairs are *complete*, meaning
neither of them is missing, would you please try the `awk` script:

```
awk '
    /<ticket>/ {f = 1; file = sprintf("Smaller_File_%05d.xml", ++c)}
    f {print > file}
    /<\/ticket>/ {f = 0; close(file)}
' BF_File.xml
```

or a one-liner (less readable):

```
awk '/<ticket>/ {f = 1; file = sprintf("Smaller_File_%05d.xml", ++c)} f {print > file} /<\/ticket>/ {f = 0; close(file)}' BF_File.xml
```

- If a line matches `<ticket>` set `f` and open a new file.
- If `f` is set, print the line to the file.
- If a line matches `</ticket>`, reset `f` and close the file.

Please modify the number of digits `%05d` according to the possible
count of splitted files.

Answer (score 1):

[You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) [parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) [with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105). Please use a dedicated XML-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead.
With its integrated [EXPath File Module](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#modulefile) you can do this all in one go:

```bash
$ xidel -s BF_File.xml -e '
  for $x at $i in //ticket return
  file:write(x"Smaller_File_{$i}.xml",$x)
'

$ xidel -s Smaller_File_1.xml Smaller_File_2.xml Smaller_File_3.xml -e '$raw'
<ticket>foo</ticket>
<ticket>bar</ticket>
<ticket>base</ticket>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
i=0
for f in BF_File.xml; do
        let i++;
        sed 's#.*<ticket>\(.*\)</ticket>#\1#' "$f" > Smaller_File_"${i}".xml
done
```

- `for f in BF_File.xml` only runs once
- only a single assignment to `i` will happen
- `sed`  regex are **greedy**: `.*` matches the longest possible string (which can include `...</ticket>...<ticket>...`)
- `sed` operates on individual lines, so the `s` command will only match `<ticket>` and `</ticket>` appear on the same line

You say the code "copies those two lines plus the content in between" but your `sed` command would throw away the two lines. You'd need something more like: `s#.*\(<ticket>.*</ticket>\)#\1#` (but it would still fail for the previous reasons)

---

With `gawk`, you can specify that `RS` is a regex.

Assuming input has the form:

```
a<ticket>b</ticket>c<ticket>d</ticket>e<ticket>f</ticket>g...
```

then setting `RS='</?ticket>'` gives records: `a` `b` `c` `d` `e` `f` `g` ...

from which the odd elements can be discarded to leave: `b` `d` `f` ...

`gawk` sets `RT` to the actual value of `RS` when each record is read so this can be saved and used to wrap the records on output.

```
gawk -v RS='</?ticket>' '
    !(NR%2) {
        out = "small" (++n) ".xml"
        print rt $0 RT > out
        close out
    }
    { rt = RT }
' big.xml
```

Comment: Note that this code assumes that `<ticket>`/`</ticket>` cannot appear except as delimiters. In actual XML that is not guaranteed. Using an XML parsing tool would be more reliable.

Comment: I'll give this a try, always good to have multiple ways to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `XML` parser: `xmllint` and a shell *while loop*:

```
cat file.xml
<root>
<ticket>foo</ticket>
<ticket>bar</ticket>
<ticket>base</ticket>
</root>
```

```
i=1
while IFS= read -r val; do 
    echo "$val" | tee "Smaller_File_$(printf '%.5d' $i).xml"
    ((i++))
done < <(xmllint --xpath '//ticket/text()' file.xml)
foo
bar
base
```

```
ls -1 Smaller_File_0*
Smaller_File_00001.xml
Smaller_File_00002.xml
Smaller_File_00003.xml
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. Always happy to have multiple ways to do something.

Comment: IMHO this is the only correct answer. Don't parse XML with anything than a XML parser. Usually, the way to thanks is to upvote/accept answers